# Can I incorporate the toolbar of a child view in the parent views toolbar tray?

Tags: wpf, toolbar

This was a common UI technique in the old days of MDI applications. I'm not using multiple documents or child windows, but I am using a simplified form of Frame navigation that switches user controls in a parent view. Is there not a way to show the child view's tool bar in the parent's tool bar tray?

Comment: Can you provide some code example? That can be possibly done by binding items from the child control into the parent view, but some further detail is needed.

Comment: There is no code needed. I just generally want to know if this is possible WPF, and if so how to do it. I have a navigation style interface. I want each page to have a different tool bar that will be added to the parent container's tool bar tray when that page is navigated too.

Comment: One way I can think of it is having your parent toolbar bind to a collection of commands (e.g. `IEnumerable<ICommand>`) exposed by the child control. Then you can create some data template for the parent toolbar that will style (show labels, images, tooltips) accordingly.

Does that help?

Comment: The solution isn't binding. If it was, I'd have a solution. I want the child's toolbar to show up when the child does, and disappear when the child does. And I don't want my parent control to have to do anything about it. This stuff was available back in the 90's with MDI in MFC. I can't believe we can't do it with WPF.